# node --experimental-modules, requested module does not provide an export named

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I've installed Node 8.9.1 (same problem happens in v10.5.0).

I'm trying to use named imports from npm packages in a file with the `.mjs`

```
import { throttle } from lodash;
```

I run:

```
node --experimental-modules index.mjs
```

and I get:

> SyntaxError: The requested module 'lodash' does not provide an export named 'throttle'
>       at ModuleJob._instantiate (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:80:21)

`--experimental-modules` are supposed to [stop being experimental in v10 LTS](http://2ality.com/2017/09/native-esm-node.html), so why haven't more module authors jumped on the bandwagon?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 imports in Node with --experimental-modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48682712/es6-imports-in-node-with-experimental-modules)

Comment: lodash-es would solve it.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

**EDITED NEW (AND MUCH BETTER) ANSWER**

The Node team is ... slow.  Meanwhile, the same guy who brought us Lodash (John-David Dalton) imagined a *brilliant* solution, and his idea is the best way to get full ES6 module support in 2019.

(In fact, I *want* to delete my earlier answer, but I've left it for historical purposes.)

The new solution is SUPER simple.

**Step #1:**

```
npm i esm
```

(https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm for package details)

**Step #2:**

```
node -r esm yourApp.js
```

That's the entirety of it: it's really just that easy. Just add `-r esm` as a Node arg, and everything just magically works (it's even less typing than `--experimental-modules`!) Thank you John-David Dalton!!!

As I said in my original answer, presumably *someday* Node will finally release full ES6 support, but when that happens adopting it will be as easy as removing "-r esm" from a few scripts :D

Finally, to give credit where due, while I didn't find it through his answer, @Divyanshu Rawat actually provided an answer with the precursor to this library long before I made this update.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

`--experimental-modules` does not have support for named exports yet:

> --experimental-modules doesn't support importing named exports from a commonjs module (except node's own built-ins).

- https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tools/issues/913

This is why you are unable to use the syntax:

```
 import { throttle } from 'lodash';
```

Instead (for now at least) you have to destruct what you need:

```
 import lodash from 'lodash';
 const { throttle } = lodash;
```

Presumably someday Node will add support for all of the ES Module features.

Comment: I disagree with the very first statement in this answer. @stackdave's `import { throttle } from lodash;` would work if lodash had been written as modules, i.e. `lodash/index.mjs` exported throttle like this `export const throttle = ...;`.

Comment: I don't understand what you're disagreeing with: Lodash is written the way it's written.  Your hypothetical talk about lodash being written some other way doesn't invalidate the answer.

Comment: is this still the case? Will named exports be supported directly by ESM?

Comment: The latest news is "ECMAScript modules are the official standard format to package JavaScript code for reuse." ... but that statement has "Stability: 1 - Experimental" status (ie. it's not true ... yet; sorry if I got your hopes up).  You can follow the progress on this page:https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html.  When that orange line below "ECMAScript Modules" isn't orange anymore, it will mean progress.

Comment: I'll just add that if you want to use that syntax in Typescript with strict mode, you should enable the "allowSyntheticDefaultImports" compiler option

Comment: Yes.  If you `node -r esm someFile.js`, then `someFile.js` can use named import syntax (eg. `import {foo} from 'someFile'`).

Comment: Sadly, for Node.js > v12.12.0 (including all Node.js 13 and Node.js 14), **this package does not work**. The issue has been opened for several months now, so I wouldn't expect much from this package. Link to the issue: [https://github.com/standard-things/esm/issues/868](https://github.com/standard-things/esm/issues/868)

Comment: Wow: it's bad enough the Node people have to make everything needlessly difficult in the first place, and require a 3rd party dev (on their own) to make a better implementation of something their entire team failed at (or at least failed to achieve in a timely manner) ... but now they're deliberately breaking things to try and force people to use their idiotic `.mjs` extension?!?  The Node organization is the absolute **worst** part of using Node :(  But still, JDD is pretty awesome, so I'd expect a fix to come soon unless the Node org makes it impossible.

Comment: P.S. Have you tried adding the `--no-esm` flag to Node itself?  I haven't upgraded my own Node version yet, but it seems that might be a workaround.

Comment: I had no problem using `node -r esm yourApp.js`  with Node.js v14.15.4. 

Super happy with this! I have been annoyed by this for days now.

Comment: esm is useless now. I think it's worthy to understand the standard way of doing one thing.

Answer (score 8):

I just had this error with nodejs express *.mjs file and `--experimental-modules` flag enabled for googleapis.

> import { google } from "googleapis";
>
> SyntaxError: The requested module 'googleapis' does not provide an export named 'google'

Solution

```
//not working!
//import { google } from "googleapis";

//working
import googleapis from "googleapis";
const { google } = googleapis;
```

I do not understand why this is the case; if anyone knows why, please comment.

Comment: This is because ESM modules have a custom concept of "named exports" rather than just exporting an object and the import statement using destructuring.

Answer (score 7):

You have to use `.mjs` extension.

> Once this has been set, files ending with .mjs will be able to be loaded as ES Modules.

reference: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html

Update:

Looks like you haven't export the method yet.

Suppose i have `hello.mjs` with content

```
export function sayHello() {
    console.log('hello')
}
```

i can use it in `index.mjs` like this

```
import {sayHello} from './hello.mjs'
sayHello()
```

Comment: thanks I've updated my answer with a new error, sorry that the propose of my answer is be able to run modules with node 8

Comment: updated. it's better if you can post the content of your code

Comment: I've realize all files imported with modueles  across the project  must have .mts extension. See the the update on my answer.

Comment: OP was asking about importing from an npm module, not their own.

Answer (score 7):

For me loading lodash as **ES Library** did the job, here is the **NPM Package** for the same.

The Lodash library exported as **ES modules**.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-es

Then you can import **utils** in normal way.

```
import { shuffle } from 'lodash-es';
```

Comment: I just added what helped me and someone downvoted it can anyone explain.

Comment: I don't know why this got downvoted originally; maybe you didn't do a good enough job of explaining it?  If it's any consolation I've actually updated my (accepted) answer to mention the `esm` module, which I believe is the successor to the one you mentioned (and FWIW I upvoted your answer).

Answer (score 1):

If lodash had been written as modules, and `lodash/index.mjs` exported `throttle`: `export const throttle = ...;`, then you'd be able to `import { throttle } from lodash;`

The problem here is that in commonjs there's no such thing as a named export. Which means that in commonjs modules export one thing only.

So think that lodash exports an object containing a property named `throttle`.

For the second part of the question, I believe people will slowly start adopting ES Modules once it's not experimental anymore. At the time of this writing, it still is (Node.js v11.14).

Answer (score 0):

@machineghost answer works. I remember also adding `'type':'module'` to package.json along with using esm with node v12(LTS) and it worked fine.## Heading ##

I updated my node to v14(current) and I got an error

```
C:\Users\andey\Documents\Project\src\app.js:1
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: 
C:\Users\andey\Documents\Project\src\app.js
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1217:13) {
code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

To fix it I had to remove `'type':'module'` from package.json.

[source](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/88562551-error-err_require_esm-must-use-import-to-load-es-module-c-node-gulpfile-js)