# ES6 imports in Node with --experimental-modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Trying to use ES6 imports in node with the -experimental-modules flag.  Specifically:

```
mkdir ma
cd ma
npm init
npm i --save moving-averages
touch index.mjs
```

Now place the following code in index.mjs:

```
import {
ma, dma, ema, sma, wma
} from 'moving-averages'

ma([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2)
```

The result is:

```
file:///home/ole/ma/index.mjs:2
  ma, dma, ema, sma, wma
  ^^
SyntaxError: The requested module does not provide an export named 'ma'
    at ModuleJob._instantiate (internal/loader/ModuleJob.js:86:19)
    at <anonymous>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: This [thread from the Node Modules Working Group](https://github.com/nodejs/modules/issues/81) explains why named imports from CommonJS modules don't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving averages currently only has a single default export. You will need to import the whole module and then you have the option to de-structure the arguments.

```
import movingAverages from 'moving-averages'

const {ma, dma, ema, sma, wma} = movingAverages;
```

Comment: I dont understand your answer. Isnt the point of named imports that the specified module does NOT NEED ANY DEFAULT EXPORT at all?

Comment: The module `moving-averages` only has a default export. If it had other experts they would be available.