# How to use redux-thunk from node server side?

Tags: node.js, redux, redux-thunk, es6-modules

(code from https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions)

The code setups a redux store and then calls dispatch on the store with some actions. The store use redux-thunk to manage async API calls.

Here is the index.js

```
    import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk'
    const { thunkMiddleware } = reduxThunk;
    import redux from 'redux';
    const { createStore } = redux;
    const { applyMiddleware } = redux;
    import { selectSubreddit, fetchPosts } from './actions.js'

    import rootReducer from './reducers.js'

    const store = createStore(
      rootReducer,
      applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)
    );

    store.dispatch(selectSubreddit('reactjs'));
    store.dispatch(fetchPosts('reactjs')).then(() => console.log(store.getState()));
```

Error after running `node index.js`

```
    (node:19229) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
    applyMiddleware [Function: applyMiddleware]
    /home/code/redux/tutorial_async_actions/node_modules/redux/lib/redux.js:648
            return middleware(middlewareAPI);
                  ^
    TypeError: middleware is not a function
        at /home/code/redux/tutorial_async_actions/node_modules/redux/lib/redux.js:648:16
        at Array.map (<anonymous>)
        at /home/code/redux/tutorial_async_actions/node_modules/redux/lib/redux.js:647:31
        at createStore (/home/code/redux/tutorial_async_actions/node_modules/redux/lib/redux.js:85:33)
        at file:///home/code/redux/tutorial_async_actions/index.js:18:15
        at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:110:37)
        at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:164:24)
```

**What do I do to get this to run?** I think this has something to do with ES6 and modules but I'm stuck... :(

I am already doing this (as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48683338/12948718))

```
import redux from 'redux';
const { createStore, applyMiddleware } = redux;
```

(I could get this to work using create-react-app ... but I would prefer to get this working without webpack et al)

---

Below the remaining code for reference.

Here the actions

```
    export const SELECT_SUBREDDIT = 'SELECT_SUBREDDIT'
    export function selectSubreddit(subreddit) {
      return {
        type: SELECT_SUBREDDIT,
        subreddit
      };
    }

    export const INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT = 'INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT'
    function invalidateSubreddit(subreddit) {
      return {
        type: INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT,
        subreddit
      };
    }

    export const REQUEST_POSTS = 'REQUEST_POSTS'
    function requestPosts(subreddit) {
      return {
        type: REQUEST_POSTS,
        subreddit
      }
    }

    export const RECEIVE_POSTS = 'RECEIVE_POSTS'
    function receivePosts(subreddit, json) {
      return {
        type: RECEIVE_POSTS,
        subreddit,
        posts: json.data.children.map(child => child.data),
        receivedAt: Date.now()
      }
    }

    export function fetchPosts(subreddit) {
      return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch(requestPosts(subreddit));

        return fetch(`https://www.reddit.com/r/${subreddit}.json`)
          .then(
            response => response.json(),
            error => console.log('An error occurred.', error)
          )
          .then(json =>
            dispatch(receivePosts(subreddit, json))
          )
      }
    }
```

and here the reducers

```
    import redux from 'redux';
    const { combineReducers } = redux;
    import {
      SELECT_SUBREDDIT,
      INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT,
      REQUEST_POSTS,
      RECEIVE_POSTS
    } from './actions.js';

    function selectedSubreddit(state = 'reactjs', action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case SELECT_SUBREDDIT:
          return action.subreddit
        default:
          return state
      }
    }

    function posts(
      state = {
        isFetching: false,
        didInvalidate: false,
        items: []
      },
      action
    ) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT:
          return Object.assign({}, state, { didInvalidate: true })
        case REQUEST_POSTS:
          return Object.assign({}, state, { isFetching: true, didInvalidate: false });
        case RECEIVE_POSTS:
          return Object.assign({}, state, {
            isFetching: false, didInvalidate: false,
            items: action.posts,
            lastUpdated: action.receivedAt
          });
        default:
          return state;

      }
    }

    function postsBySubreddit(state = {}, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT:
        case RECEIVE_POSTS:
        case REQUEST_POSTS:
          return Object.assign({}, state, {
            [action.subreddit]: posts(state[action.subreddit], action)
          });
        default:
          return state
      }

    }

    const rootReducer = combineReducers({
      postsBySubreddit,
      selectedSubreddit
    });

    export default rootReducer;
```

Here package.json

```
    {
      "name": "redux_async_actions",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "type": "module",
      "dependencies": {
        "redux": "^4.0.5",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ES6 imports in Node with --experimental-modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48682712/es6-imports-in-node-with-experimental-modules)

Comment: @Zydnar I have updated my question. I am already doing that (first import whole module then de-structure).

Comment: Using babel is totaly ok for target node, especially if your code supposed to work for different versions of node, I'm not sure about using webpack though since webpack is rather for WEB. So maybe just use babel?

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of babel. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I originally asked the question but I lost my login)

I got this to work using the [node module system](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) (i.e. using the function require). The ES6 export / import should work but I guess one or other of the modules I am trying to use (redux, redux-thunk) does not play nicely with ES6 export / import.

Essentially I converted the `export` statements to `exports.` statements

`export function(...) {...}` => `exports.myFunction = function(...) {...}`

And the I converted `import` statements to `require` statements.

`import {myFunction} from './somefile.js'`=> `const module = require('./somefile.js')`

Below the code as in the question but using require.

index.js

```
    const redux = require('redux');
    const { createStore, applyMiddleware } = redux;

    const ReduxThunk = require('redux-thunk').default

    const actions = require('./actions.js');
    const { selectSubreddit, fetchPosts } = actions;

    const rootReducer = require('./reducers.js');

    const store = createStore(
      rootReducer.rootReducer,
      applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk)
    );

    store.dispatch(selectSubreddit('reactjs'));
    store.dispatch(fetchPosts('reactjs')).then(() => console.log(store.getState()));
```

actions.js

```
    const fetch = require('cross-fetch');

    const SELECT_SUBREDDIT = 'SELECT_SUBREDDIT'
    exports.SELECT_SUBREDDIT = SELECT_SUBREDDIT
    function selectSubreddit(subreddit) {
      return {
        type: SELECT_SUBREDDIT,
        subreddit
      };
    }
    exports.selectSubreddit = selectSubreddit;

    const INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT = 'INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT'
    exports.INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT = INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT
    function invalidateSubreddit(subreddit) {
      return {
        type: INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT,
        subreddit
      };
    }

    const REQUEST_POSTS = 'REQUEST_POSTS'
    exports.REQUEST_POSTS = REQUEST_POSTS
    function requestPosts(subreddit) {
      return {
        type: REQUEST_POSTS,
        subreddit
      }
    }

    const RECEIVE_POSTS = 'RECEIVE_POSTS'
    exports.RECEIVE_POSTS = RECEIVE_POSTS
    function receivePosts(subreddit, json) {
      return {
        type: RECEIVE_POSTS,
        subreddit,
        posts: json.data.children.map(child => child.data),
        receivedAt: Date.now()
      }
    }

    function fetchPosts(subreddit) {
      return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch(requestPosts(subreddit));

        return fetch(`https://www.reddit.com/r/${subreddit}.json`)
          .then(
            response => response.json(),
            error => console.log('An error occurred.', error)
          )
          .then(json =>
            dispatch(receivePosts(subreddit, json))
          )
      }
    }
    exports.fetchPosts = fetchPosts;
```

reducers.js

```
    const redux = require('redux');
    const { combineReducers } = redux;
    const actions = require('./actions.js');
    const {
      SELECT_SUBREDDIT,
      INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT,
      REQUEST_POSTS,
      RECEIVE_POSTS
    } = actions;

    function selectedSubreddit(state = 'reactjs', action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case SELECT_SUBREDDIT:
          return action.subreddit
        default:
          return state
      }
    }

    function posts(
      state = {
        isFetching: false,
        didInvalidate: false,
        items: []
      },
      action
    ) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT:
          return Object.assign({}, state, { didInvalidate: true })
        case REQUEST_POSTS:
          return Object.assign({}, state, { isFetching: true, didInvalidate: false });
        case RECEIVE_POSTS:
          return Object.assign({}, state, {
            isFetching: false, didInvalidate: false,
            items: action.posts,
            lastUpdated: action.receivedAt
          });
        default:
          return state;

      }
    }

    function postsBySubreddit(state = {}, action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT:
        case RECEIVE_POSTS:
        case REQUEST_POSTS:
          return Object.assign({}, state, {
            [action.subreddit]: posts(state[action.subreddit], action)
          });
        default:
          return state
      }

    }

    const rootReducer = combineReducers({
      postsBySubreddit,
      selectedSubreddit
    });

    exports.rootReducer = rootReducer;
```

package.json (notice package does not have `"type": "module",`)

```
    {
      "name": "basic_example_only_node",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "cross-fetch": "^3.0.4",
        "redux": "^4.0.5",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
      }
    }
```