# How Can I Use Named Module Exports in Node 16 App?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, es6-modules

I'm using **Node 16.3.0** and **Express 4.17.1** (though my Node version is flexible)

I have a `session.js` file that's like this:

```
// session.js

exports.fetchUserId = async function(token){
  ...
}

exports.save = async function(userId){
  ...
}
```

Then over in my `app.js` file, I try to do this:

```
// app.js

import session from './session.js'
```

I get the following error:

```
import session from './session.js'
       ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module './session.js' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

...and then I want to use `session` in `app.js` like this:

```
let userId = await session.fetchUserId(req.body.token)
```

I have tried the following without any luck:

1. Adding `"type": "module"` to `package.json`
2. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47277887/node-experimental-modules-requested-module-does-not-provide-an-export-named) by doing `npm i esm`
3. Using `nodemon --experimental-modules app.js`

My code works fine when used in a [NuxtJS](https://nuxtjs.org/) project, but I'm trying a vanilla Node/Express app and the named exports don't work.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` file? Specifically, do you have `"type": "module"` in that file?

Comment: Yes, see `#1` above. I have `"type": "module"` in there.

Comment: Unfortunately node doesn't support es6 module imports by default, so you'd have to go with one of the following solutions: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-an-es6-import-in-node-js/amp/ - Alternative would be to go with commonJS imports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in your code is that you are mixing the ES modules with CommonJS modules.

By default, node treats each javascript file as a [CommonJS module](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/modules.html) but with the following in the `package.json` file

```
"type": "module"
```

you are telling node to treat each javascript file as a [Ecmascript module](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/esm.html) but in `session.js` file, you are using the CommonJS module syntax to export the functions.

#### Solutions

You could solve your problem using one of the following options:

- Change the extension of the `session.js` file to `.cjs`. (Don't forget to change the extension in the import statement in `app.js` file as well).

  Changing the extension to `.cjs` will tell node to treat `session.cjs` file as a CommonJS module.
- Just use ES modules and change the exports in `session.js` file as shown below:

  ```
  export const fetchUserId = async function(token){ ... }

  export const save = async function(userId) { ... }
  ```

  and change the import statement in `app.js` file as:

  ```
  import * as session from "./session.js";
  ```

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. Great answer, thank you!